# Redirect http to https on dev domain only (same server as live domain)

Tags: https, redirect, apache2

Providing I have 1 Ubuntu server which holds two sites (they are subdomains and also they hold code for other subdomains):

- house.example.com (also I have api.example.com) - production site
- house-dev.example.com (also have api-dev.example.com) - development site

How could I redirect all http request for house-dev.example.com  to https://house-dev.example.com and all http request for api-dev.example.com to https://api-dev.example.com?

My conf files in sites-enabled are:

For house.example.com

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias house.example.com api.example.com
    (...)
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    (...)
</VirtualHost>
```

For house-dev.example.com:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias house-dev.example.com api-dev.example.com
    Redirect "/" "https://house-dev.example.com"
    (...)
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    (...)
</VirtualHost>
```

How could I redirect all http traffic of house-dev (and associated api-dev) to https?

I have all .crt and .key files in place and paths are all correct. I am on about the `Redirect` method.

I have tried `Redirect "/" "https://house-dev.example.com"` and it works fine for `house-dev`, but when I try `http://api-dev.example.com` the redirection goes to `https://house-dev.example.com`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have tried Redirect "/" "https://house-dev.example.com" and it works
>   fine for house-dev, but when I try http://api-dev.example.com the
>   redirection goes to https://house-dev.example.com.

Of course it does because both hostnames are handled by the same virtual host, and you have a fixed redirect to `house-dev.example.com`.

A simple fix for this would be to just create a separate port 80 vhost for each hostname, and have the correct redirect entry in each.

Alternatively you could use `RewriteRule` to perform to redirect. Something like the following (untested)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,QSA,L]
```

It's also apparently possible to use variables with `Redirect`, if you use it inside a location block. The following comes from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40289269/using-redirectmatch-with-http-host-in-the-destination

```
<Location "/">
    Redirect "https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}"
</Location>
```